# Case insensitivity in Python strings

Tags: python

I know that you can use the ctypes library to perform case insensitive comparisons on strings, however I would like to perform case insensitive replacement too. Currently the only way I know to do this is with Regex's and it seems a little poor to do so via that.

Is there a case insensitive version of replace()?

Comment: Why do you think regex is poor?  What's wrong with regex?

Comment: Seems an overly complicated way to solve a simple problem, like shipping a single bedside cabinet in a truck.

Comment: nah -- there should be one, and preferably only one, obvious way to do it.  Since re are great for case-insensitive sub, it would break this design principle to make str more complicated just to offer one more way to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can supply the flag re.IGNORECASE to functions in the re module as described in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
matcher = re.compile(myExpression, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Surely re.sub would be better?

Comment: You would use the object returned by compile as the pattern in re.sub.

Comment: Ahhh, and if I were using it a lot then it'd be faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using `re` is the best solution even if you think it's complicated.

To replace all occurrences of `'abc'`, `'ABC'`, `'Abc'`, etc., with `'Python'`, say:

```
re.sub(r'(?i)abc', 'Python', a)
```

Example session:

```
>>> a = 'abc  asd   Abc  asd  ABCDE    XXAbCXX'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)abc', 'Python', a)
'Python  asd   Python  asd  PythonDE    XXPythonXX'
>>>
```

Note how embedding `(?i)` at the start of the regexp makes it case sensitive. Also note the `r'...'` string literal for the regexp (which in this specific case is redundant but helps as soon as your regexp has backslashes `(\)` in them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert it all to lowercase then do the replace. But is obviously an issue if you want to retain the original case.

I would do a regex replace, you can instruct the Regex engine to ignore casing all together.

See [this site](http://www.akeric.com/blog/?p=312) for an example.