# Python: Replace string with prefixStringSuffix keeping original case, but ignoring case when searching for match

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, nltk

So what I'm trying to do is replace a string "keyword" with 
    `"<b>keyword</b>"`
in a larger string.

Example:

myString = "HI there. You should higher that person for the job. Hi hi."

keyword = "hi"

result I would  want would be:

`result = "<b>HI</b> there. You should higher that person for the job.`
`<b>Hi</b> <b>hi</b>."`

I will not know what the keyword until the user types the keyword 
and won't know the corpus (myString) until the query is run.

I found a solution that works most of the time, but has some false positives, 
`namely it would return "<b>hi<b/>gher"`which is not what I want. Also note that I 
am trying to preserve the case of the original text, and the matching should take 
place irrespective of case. so if the keyword is "hi" it should replace 
`HI with <b>HI</b> and hi with <b>hi</b>.`

The closest I have come is using a slightly derived version of this:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576715/
but I still could not figure out how to do a second pass of the string to fix all of the false positives mentioned above.

Or using the NLTK's WordPunctTokenizer (which simplifies some things like punctuation)
but I'm not sure how I would put the sentences back together given it does not 
have a reverse function and I want to keep the original punctuation of myString. Essential, doing a concatenation of all the tokens does not return the original 
string. For example I would not want to replace "7 - 7" with "7-7" when regrouping the tokens into its original text if the original text had "7 - 7".

Hope that was clear enough. Seems like a simple problem, but its a turned out a little more difficult then I thought.

Comment: Looks like maybe a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787842/case-insensitivity-in-python-strings?

Comment: That's similar, but there is more requirements then simply doing a case insensitive replace of a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ok?

```
>>> import re
>>> myString = "HI there. You should higher that person for the job. Hi hi."
>>> keyword = "hi"
>>> search = re.compile(r'\b(%s)\b' % keyword, re.I)
>>> search.sub('<b>\\1</b>', myString)
'<b>HI</b> there. You should higher that person for the job. <b>Hi</b> <b>hi</b>.'
```

The key to the whole thing is using [word boundaries](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), [groups](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and the [re.I flag](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.I).

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted. I might have to edit what constitutes a word boundary is as stated by Dave B, but that should be easy to edit and I would have to look though the data and figure that out later (if I need to). Otherwise this is exactly what I needed and I'm sure covers all cases I could come up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this very easily with `re.sub` using the word boundary assertion `\b`, which only matches at a word boundary:

```
import re

def SurroundWith(text, keyword, before, after):
  regex = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % keyword, re.IGNORECASE)
  return regex.sub(r'%s\0%s' % (before, after), text)
```

Then you get:

```
>>> SurroundWith('HI there. You should hire that person for the job. '
...              'Hi hi.', 'hi', '<b>', '</b>')
'<b>HI</b> there. You should hire that person for the job. <b>Hi</b> <b>hi</b>.'
```

If you have more complicated criteria for what constitutes a "word boundary," you'll have to do something like:

```
def SurroundWith2(text, keyword, before, after):
  regex = re.compile(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9])(%s)([^a-zA-Z0-9])' % keyword,
                     re.IGNORECASE)
  return regex.sub(r'\1%s\2%s\3' % (before, after), text)
```

You can modify the `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` groups to match anything you consider a "non-word."

Comment: I ran
before = '<b>'
after ='</b>'
text = "HI there. You should higher that person for the job. Hi hi."
keyword = 'hi'
print 'result = ', SurroundWith( text , keyword, before, after)

and got 
result =  <b>

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be regular expression...

```
import re
def reg(keyword, myString) :
   regx = re.compile(r'\b(' + keyword + r')\b', re.IGNORECASE)
   return regx.sub(r'<b>\1</b>', myString)
```

of course, you must first make your keyword "regular expression safe" (quote any regex special characters).

Answer (score -1):

Here's one suggestion, from the nitpicking committee.  :-)

```
myString = "HI there. You should higher that person for the job. Hi hi."

myString.replace('higher','hire')
```