# Replace part of string in Python-

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace part of a string in Python. In particular, I want to get rid of the structure `"Hello[hi, ... ,bye]"`, where the dots represent any length of characters.

I have found that in [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x) it is explained how to use replace, but I can not figure out how to match the pattern "Hello[hi, ... ,bye]" with an arbitrary piece of string in place of '...'

Example 1:

```
text= "Hello.hi[. Hello[hi, my name is alice ,bye] ,bye]"
```

I want: `result= "Hello.hi[., 123 my name is alice 456 ,bye]"`

But I want the same pattern also to work for example 2:

```
text= "Hello.hi[., Hello[hi, have a good day ,bye] ,bye]"
```

I want: `result= "Hello.hi[., 123 have a good day 456 ,bye]"`

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`.

```
text= "Hello[hi, my name is alice ,bye] "
text.replace('hi,', '123').replace(',bye', '456')
>>> 'Hello[123 my name is alice 456] '
```

Same would work for "Hello[hi, have a good day ,bye] "

Comment: You don't replace enough. It should be: `text.replace('Hello[hi,', '123').replace(',bye] ', '456')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I have already tried that, but I don't get what I want. I have edited the post to make the problem more clear.

Comment: @yago: I see. You should absolutely be using `regex` (`import re`) search/replace then. See the manuals on the internet for using it with Python.

Comment: @Artur Barseghyan,Thanks!  yes,  I have been reading about regex, but I am a beginner and I could not solved it yet, so I posted here in case anyone could illuminate me. I will keep reading though. Thanks again.

Comment: @yago: Do you only want to replace words within the opening and closing brackets? Otherwise, please, make your question very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
index_l=[]
x=0
for i in text:
    if i == ',':index_l.append(i)
output = text[index_l[0]:index_l[1]]
print output
```

Comment: This only strips out the string contained within the commas!

Comment: Thanks @Ubdus Samad, but this does not work either because I have a large text with lots of comas. The examples are only some sentences. I was wondering if a could match the whole pattern "Hello[hi, ... ,bye]"

Comment: Learn regular expressions then!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I have solved the problem using this post [Python: Replace string with prefixStringSuffix keeping original case, but ignoring case when searching for match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818691/python-replace-string-with-prefixstringsuffix-keeping-original-case-but-ignori)

Solution

```
import re
text="Hello[hi, my name is alice ,bye]"
search = re.compile(r'Hello\[hi,(.*?),bye\]')
a=search.sub('123\\1 456', text)
print(a)
```